# how to remove a character in string in PHP

Tags: php, string

I just want to remove character "c" from variable $a

```
  $a="a,b,c,d";
```

and the variable $a must in this format

```
$a="a,b,d";
```

I tried array(), but it not useful for my work.

Comment: `str_replace("c,", "", $a);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are going for one of the [str_replace()](https://www.php.net/str_replace) methods don't forget to include an extra , in front of your string (and stripping it afterwards) because you would have trouble stripping of the first character (if chosen).

`$str = substr(str_replace(",c", "", "," . $a), 1);`

Answer (score 1):

Use [`str_replace()`](http://php.net/str_replace).

```
<?php
$a="a,b,c,d";
echo str_replace("c,", "", $a); //output: a,b,d
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`str_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php).

```
$str = str_replace(",c", "", $a);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`str_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php), or you could [break the string into parts](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) and [remove the unwanted one](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php):

```
$parts = explode(',', $a);
$parts = array_diff($a, array('c'));
$a = implode(',', $a);
```